# Discrimination prevention in data mining

Tags: data-mining

I am trying to implement a system to prevent discrimination in data mining using the preprocessing technique, using the Adult Dataset. So far, I have preprocessed the data and extracted the frequent classification rules. But am unable to go forward with calculating the elift, elb values for the rules, which is a major step. My work is based on the paper "Methodology for direct and indirect discrimination prevention in data mining". So if anyone could help me out with this, it would be really great.

Comment: Could you post some of your code?

Comment: @RickSmith I haven't started the coding for calculating those values, thats what I need help with.

Comment: What language are you using?